# Gem Load Error is: undefined method `type_cast_from_database' for class `ArJdbc::MSSQL::UUIDType'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, jdbc, jruby

I'm struggling for many hours now using activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter with Rails 5.1 (or 5.2). I've installed ant to be able to compile the gem during the bundling. The bundle process runs fine but when I want to start rails I'm just getting

```
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `type_cast_from_database' for class `ArJdbc::MSSQL::UUIDType'
```

I've googled a lot but didn't find a solution or a hint what causes this error. Here is some more information:

**Java version:** Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)

**Ruby:** jruby-9.1.17.0

**OS:** Win10

**Part of the Gemfile**

```
ruby '2.3.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'

gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', github: "jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter", :branch => "51-stable"
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter',github: "jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter",:branch => "51-stable"
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter','~> 1.8.0'
```

**The Backtrace**

```
Q:\Ruby\jruby-9.1.17.0\bin\jruby.exe -S rails s
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `type_cast_from_database' for class `ArJdbc::MSSQL::UUIDType'
Backtrace for gem load error is:
org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2841:in `alias_method'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/lib/arjdbc/mssql/types.rb:319:in `<class:UUIDType>'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/lib/arjdbc/mssql/types.rb:316:in `<module:MSSQL>'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/lib/arjdbc/mssql/types.rb:2:in `<module:ArJdbc>'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/lib/arjdbc/mssql/types.rb:1:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956:in `require'
o:/bundler/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
o:/bundler/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
o:/bundler/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/lib/arjdbc/mssql/adapter.rb:1:in `<module:(root)>'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/lib/arjdbc/mssql/adapter.rb:37:in `<module:MSSQL>'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/lib/arjdbc/mssql/adapter.rb:30:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956:in `require'
o:/bundler/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
o:/bundler/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
o:/bundler/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/lib/arjdbc/mssql/adapter.rb:29:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956:in `require'
o:/bundler/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
o:/bundler/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
o:/bundler/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/lib/arjdbc/mssql.rb:1:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956:in `require'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/lib/arjdbc/mssql.rb:2:in `block in (root)'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735:in `each'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter/lib/activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter.rb:1:in `block in (root)'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735:in `each'
o:/bundler/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-4eebab4df17d/activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter/lib/activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter.rb:2:in `(root)'
Q:/Ruby/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:1:in `(root)'
Q:/Ruby/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956:in `require'
Q:/Ruby/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1765:in `tap'
Q:/Ruby/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
Q:/Ruby/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
O:/git/xxxx/config/application.rb:7:in `(root)'
o:/bundler/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:1:in `(root)'
o:/bundler/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `perform'
o:/bundler/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
o:/bundler/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:

  block in require at Q:/Ruby/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:84
              each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735
  block in require at Q:/Ruby/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76
              each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735
          require at Q:/Ruby/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65
          require at Q:/Ruby/jruby-9.1.17.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler.rb:114
            <main> at O:/git/xxx/config/application.rb:7
          require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:956
  block in (root) at o:/bundler/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:1
              tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1765
          perform at o:/bundler/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133
          perform at o:/bundler/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130
              run at o:/bundler/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27
    invoke_command at o:/bundler/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126
          dispatch at o:/bundler/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387
          perform at o:/bundler/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63
            <main> at o:/bundler/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44
          require at org/jruby/R
```

Comment: Im trying to use `activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter` as well, no luck :( I cant even get it past `bundle install`...

Comment: Have you tried using older version of rails? I cannot understand the gem if it can handle MSSQL. From my understanding, yes it can, but im not sure why we cannot make it work. Which is why I am trying to see if older version of rails will work with it.

Comment: have you found a solution on making it work with rails 5? Would greatly appreciate any updates on this

Comment: according to the devs the jdbc mssql driver is not ready for rails 5.2

Comment: yeah thats too bad. i ended up downgrading to rails 4 since i need to work with windows environment. Managed to make it work in production (windows server 2016, MSSQL, active directory, jruby on rails)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with older rails version: `4.2.10`. Here is my gemfile below.
After that i can run `rails s`, `rails c` and connect to my mssql db.
Note this is just the from the `rails new app_name` command.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }



# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.10'
# Use jdbcsqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.20'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.20'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyrhino'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
# gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Here is my config/database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: jdbcmssql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  mode: dblib
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("MSSQL_HOST") { 'localhost' } %>
  port: <%= ENV.fetch("MSSQL_PORT") { 1433 } %>
  username: SA
  password: '!P4ssw0rd'

development:
  <<: *default
  database: development_mssql
```

Here is output when i run `rbenv local`:

```
$ rbenv local
jruby-9.2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

AR-JDBC does not support MS-SQL for AR **>= 5.0**
there simply wasn't enough resources to implement the SQLServer adapter.

however, the sqlserver adapter seems to have JRuby support these days.
there's some minor details where it behaves differently, but not much to worry about (except that it might be noticeably slower due pure .rb parts).

Comment: how do you setup the `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` with jruby + rails 5?
(1) it depends on the `tiny_tds` gem which cannot work with jruby (2) i tried it with rails5 and i experienced error with the `alias_method_chain` being deprecated in rails5.

Comment: hoping you can shed more light on this :) i spent a lot of time on this and ended up downgrading to rails 4.2.10 with `activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter` just to make it work on windows. hopefully i can set it up in production environment as well.