# How to use jruby/activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter to a brand new rails app (preferrably rails 5+)

Tags: jdbc, jrubyonrails, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to create a new Rails app using JRuby, and my Gemfile looks like:

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.7'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'therubyrhino'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :development do
  gem 'listen'
end
```

I run `bundle install` and it installs successfully.
Problem is when I run either `rails s` or `rails c`:

> Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter'.
>
> Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::Format
>
> Backtrace for gem load error is:
>
> /app/jruby-9.2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:13:in `module:TypeCast'
>
> /app/jruby-9.2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:7:in `module:Jdbc'
>
> /app/jruby-9.2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:4:in `module:ConnectionAdapters'
>
> /app/jruby-9.2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.22/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/type_cast.rb:3:in `'

The question is: Is `activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter` compatible with Rails5?
Because my requirement is to use JRuby and MS SQL. It seems like this is the only gem available.

If it cannot support Rails 5, can it support Rails 4? What rails 4 version?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it in 4.2.10 and it works, with setting the version for the gem.

See my answer in this question, which has my settings:
[Gem Load Error is: undefined method `type_cast_from_database' for class `ArJdbc::MSSQL::UUIDType'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363400/gem-load-error-is-undefined-method-type-cast-from-database-for-class-arjdbc/51377180#51377180)

About rails 5 though, I dont know for sure.